# Change a Method depend on Iterator to be depend on ArrayList or any Alternatives (Java)

Tags: java, oop, methods, iterator

this is a part of a program that maintain accidents in a country
**this method (depend on Iterator) adds an accident but it checks if there is duplication or not before adding:**

```
public void addAcci(Accident acci) throws DupliactionException {
    DateFormat dateft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    Iterator<Accident> it = this.publishedAccident.iterator(); //start from here //P.S:publishedAccident is an ArrayList
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next().equals(acci)) {
            throw new DupliactionException("Accident duplication at:\n"
                    + "Duplication Reason:- Duplication in date " + dateft.format(acci.getAccidentDateAndTime()));
        }
    }
    this.publishedAccidentData.add(acci);
}
```

**I don't want the method depend on Iterator so I change it to be like this:**

```
    public void addAcci(Accident acci) throws DupliactionException {
    DateFormat dateft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    ArrayList<Accident> it = this.publishedAccidentData;
        for (Accident accident : it) {
          if (it.contains(accidenet)) {
            throw new DupliactionException("Accident duplication at:\n"
                    + "Duplication Reason:- Duplication in date " + dateFormat.format(acci.getAccidentDateAndTime()));
        }  
        }
    
    this.publishedAccidentData.add(accidenet);
}
```

**So, This Change is Correct and do the same thing or not?**
***if not please provide simplest answer because I'm Studying Java OOP I'm not expert.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That change is clearly not correct.

For one have a look at this:

```
for (Accident accident : it) {
  if (it.contains(accidenet)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Here you are iterating over element in  `it` and thus `it.contains(accident)` will *always* be true.

However, you were on the right track already. Have a look at the original code, especially the following condition:

```
if(it.next().equals(acci)) { ... }
```

This indicates that your elements aleady make proper use of `equals()` which means checking for a duplicate would be as simple as this:

```
if( publishedAccidentData.contains(acci)) {
  //throw exception here
}
```

Note that `contains(acci)` will basically be the same as iterating and checking yourself, e.g. it's more or less this:

```
 for( Accident accident : publishedAccidentData ) {
   if( accident.equals(acci) ) {
     //throw exception here
   }
 }
```

So using `contains()` would be more concise while iterating yourself would enable you to do different checks (e.g. if `equals()` doesn't match your needs).

Comment: sorry I mean acci not accident.

Comment: @JimHenry in that case the logic would do the correct thing but it would be unnecessarily slow. `it.contains(acci)` would already iterate over the list so you'd be iterating twice and that outer loop is not needed at all (you're not even using `accident` in that case).

Comment: Okay I understand it, but the change that I do to be ArrayList in this case is correct ?

Comment: @JimHenry assuming `publishedAccidentData` is an array list then it would be ok. You actually don't need that additional reference `it` and just could use `publishedAccidentData` but even if you want to have that reference you might want use `List<Accident>` instead (you should always try to use interfaces instead of concrete implementations if that's possible).

Comment: `public void addOAccident(Accident accident) throws DupliactionException {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
            
            for (Accident acci : publishedAccidentData) {
              if (publishedAccidentData.equals(accident)) {
                throw new DupliactionException("Accident duplication at:\n"
                        + "Duplication Reasone:- Duplicatin in date " + dateFormat.format(accident.getAccidentDateAndTime()));
            }  
            }
        
        this.publishedAccidentData.add(accident);
    }`

Comment: This will be correct ? (I Update last comment)

Comment: @JimHenry it looks correct though it's hard to read that much code from a comment. Note that if you'd use a set you'd not have to deal with checking for duplicates yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Both the code does not do the same thing. The `if` condition in the second piece of code you have used is wrong. It should be `if (accident.equals(acci))`

Comment: Ok, Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need for loop at all to check an accident is present in the ArrayList or not. an if() condition will be sufficient

let's assume you have Accident class with two fields (date, place) then you have to override the equals method to check equality of two accident objects. like below

```
class Accident {
    String date;
    String place;

    public Accident(String date, String place) {
            this.date = date;
            this.place = place;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Accident accident = (Accident) o;
            return Objects.equals(date, accident.date) &&
                    Objects.equals(place, accident.place);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(date, place);
    }
```

}

And you have an ArrayList of Accidents which contains a1, a2 Accident class objects and if you want to check a new a3 object present in the ArrayList you can do that like below

```
ArrayList<Accident> list = new ArrayList();

Accident a1 = new Accident("11/11/2011", "USA");
Accident a2 = new Accident("11/11/2012", "UK");

list.add(a1);
list.add(a2);

Accident a3 = new Accident("11/11/2011", "USA");

if (list.contains(a3)) {
   System.out.println("Already existed")
}
```